# Is it unsafe to directly assign a URL hash parameter value to a Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xss

I'm looking at [an article](https://medium.com/@l_e/writing-a-wizard-in-react-8dafbce6db07) and on writing wizards in React, and having each step being associated with a URL. The author uses the "hash" part of the URL to specify the step, and assigns to `this.state.currentStep`. They comment that this is unsafe.

```
class BasicWizard extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      steps: []
      currentStep: location.hash //obvs this is an unsafe way to do this -- this example is for conceptual purposes only
    };
  }
```

My question:

why is this unsafe? My guess is it's a XSS hazard, but wouldn't this input be converted to a string by React anyway? The way I see it, this would only be unsafe if I were using `_dangerouslySetInnerHTML` somewhere.

If it is unsafe: how to make safe?

Answer (score 1):

Location.hash is not unsafe because it returns just a string. 
See here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

So what makes it dangerous?
It becomes dangerous when you use it dangerously.
Dangerous ways of using it:

- Merge it unescaped with your html (_dangerouslySetInnerHTML)
- Calling eval() on it
- Use this input unescaped in a sql query
- ...

But doing sth. like

```
if(location.hash === 'login') {
}
```

or assigning it to a variabe is not unsafe. What you do with that variable although can be unsafe (see above list).